# View Item Form Tabs

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jslink

I am new to JSLink and am trying to separate fields of the View Item form into tabs rather than the New Item form (tried using this on DispForm, showed tabs but not different fields). Are there any examples or ways to modify this to work on the view form?

Link: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-b2eedf92#content

```
var currentFormUniqueId; 
var currentFormWebPartId; 

// Use "Multi String" javascript to embed the required css 
var MultiString = function (f) { 
    return f.toString().split('\n').slice(1, -1).join('\n'); 
} 

//CSS would go here

var tabsObj = [ 
["General", ["Title", "Age", "Married", "Mobile", "SSN"]], 
["Work", ["Manager", "Salary", "Phone", "Email"]], 
["Other", ["Comments"]] 
]; 


(function () { 

// jQuery library is required in this sample 
// Fallback to loading jQuery from a CDN path if the local is unavailable 
(window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>')); 

var tabsContext = {}; 
tabsContext.OnPreRender = TabsOnPreRender; 
tabsContext.OnPostRender = TabsOnPostRender; 


// accordionContext.OnPostRender = accordionOnPostRender; 
tabsContext.Templates = {}; 

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(tabsContext); 

})(); 

function TabsOnPreRender(ctx) { 
if (!currentFormUniqueId) { 

    currentFormUniqueId = ctx.FormUniqueId; 
    currentFormWebPartId = "WebPart" + ctx.FormUniqueId; 

    jQuery(document).ready(function () { 

        var tabHTMLTemplate = "<li class='{class}'><a href='#{Index}'>{Title}</a></li>"; 
        var tabClass; 
        var tabsHTML = ""; 

        for (var i = 0; i < tabsObj.length; i++) { 
            tabClass = ""; 
            if (i == 0){ tabClass = "active";} 
            tabsHTML += tabHTMLTemplate.replace(/{Index}/g, i).replace(/{Title}/g, tabsObj[i][0]).replace(/{class}/g, tabClass) 
        } 

        jQuery("#" + currentFormWebPartId).prepend("<ul class='tabs'>" + tabsHTML + "</ul>"); 


        jQuery('.tabs li a').on('click', function (e) { 
            var currentIndex = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace("#",""); 
            showTabControls(currentIndex); 
            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }); 

        showTabControls(0); 

        jQuery("#" + currentFormWebPartId).prepend("<!--mce:0-->"); 
    }); 

} 
} 

function TabsOnPostRender(ctx) { 
var controlId = ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Name + "_" + ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Id; 
jQuery("[id^='" + controlId + "']").closest("tr").attr('id', 'tr_' + ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Name).hide(); 
} 

function showTabControls(index) 
{ 
jQuery("#" + currentFormWebPartId + " [id^='tr_']").hide(); 

for (var i = 0; i < tabsObj[index][1].length; i++) { 
    jQuery("[id^='tr_" + tabsObj[index][1][i] + "']").show(); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace functions TabsOnPostRender and showTabControls:

```
function TabsOnPostRender(ctx) {
    var controlId = ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Name;
    jQuery("a[name^='SPBookmark_" + controlId + "']").closest("tr").hide();
}

function showTabControls(index ){
    jQuery("a[name^='SPBookmark_']").closest("tr").hide();
    for (var i = 0; i < tabsObj[index][1].length; i++) {
        jQuery("a[name^='SPBookmark_" + tabsObj[index][1][i] + "']").closest("tr").show();
    }
}
```